# Implementation of Jacobi theta functions in Matlab

Tags: special-functions, matlab, theta-functions

I need Jacobi theta functions for my Matlab program. The functions are not included in the predefined Matlab functions. Doing a simple Google search, I found a [package developed by Moiseev I. in 2008](http://moiseevigor.github.io/elliptic/#ellipj-jacobis-elliptic-functions). However, since there are different systems of notation for Jacobi theta functions, I cannot identify the parameters $M$ and $U$ (inputs) used in this function. I interest in this type 3 Jacobi theta function (function of two variables, an elliptic and a modular variable):

$$ \vartheta_{3}(u,q)= \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} q^{n^2} e^{2inu}$$

Can anyone please help identify the $M$ and $U$ inputs for the Matlab function in terms of $u$ and $q$?